# Blender Donut Tutorial: Stretching the sprinkle causes a large distortion

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am on part 10 of Blender Guru's donut tutorial for Blender 3.0:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLw0HwphXO0

At 3:40 he increases the length of the sprinkle. I try to do this with the "Grab" function by pressing 'G' on the keyboard, but it ends up stretching the sprinkle vertically as well, as I show in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9dJhRAIlByE

Can anyone help me fix this problem? I would greatly appreciate any help!

[image]

Comment: He doesn't explain, this time, that he's moving the selection under a constraint. i.e GY, for 'move along the Y axis', not just G, for 'move'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's the *Include Non-Edited* option of the *Snap* tool that messes up your operation (not sure what it is for though), so either disable it or disable the *Snap* tool.

Comment: Oh my god thank you @moonboots. I was having this exact issue and it was driving me insane! <3